# leaflet + QGIS SERVER : COORS - PREFLIGHT REQUEST FAILS

Tags: leaflet, qgis, preflight

I am struggling with this case:

I use to have a web site with http protocol. Insite the pages a leaflet interface that ask for services (maps) to a different domain QGIS server.
That used to works perfectly: all the GET header requests was replayed by QGIS SERVER with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * (wildcard) and status 200

When I add the certificate (https) to the original web site, Chrome have started to send to QGIS SERVER preflight CORS request (with "OPTION" mode).

But, in this case, QGIS SERVER doesn't replay (0 byte replay). So Chrome gives an error: "A cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) request was blocked because the response to the associated preflight request failed, had an unsuccessful HTTP status code, and/or was a redirect.
To fix this issue, ensure all CORS preflight OPTIONS requests are answered with a successful HTTP status code (2xx) and do not redirect."

ANYWAY the leaflet interface receives the map data from QGIS even if there is that error...
I can see on chrome the GET request as well. The QGIS SERVER replays with status 200, as well.

AT THE END I HAVE A LOT OF THIS ERRORS BUT I RECEIVE THE DATA ANYWAY.

I AM SEARCHING A WAY EITHER TO DISABLE THE PREFLIGHT REQUEST TO QGIS SERVER domain OR A WAY TO CONFIG QGIS SERVER (that is mine but it is elsewhere) TO REPLAY TO PREFLIGHT REQUEST

THANKS IN ADVICE.

FRANCO